# how to validate user role during login button click event in login control?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, roleprovider, login-control

I have a login control in my asp.net webform i uses the roles manager...

i have two roles admin and vendors

i want when user enter username and password in login control then on login button click event it validates either the user is admin or vendors if vendor is admin then it will redirect to default.aspx other wise stay on login page with error. ...

how to do this using vb.net ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4z6b5d42.aspx

```
if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Username", "Rolegroup"))
        {
         Response.Redirect( "~/Admin/Adminpage.aspx");
        }

else
        {
          lblMessage.Text = "Error logging in";
        }
```

Comment: Protected Sub Login3_LoggingIn(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginCancelEventArgs) Handles Login3.LoggingIn

    End Sub

Comment: i want during loggin via login control if username and password of user is in admin role then it redirect to Default.aspx other wise ...its shows an error message on login page and stays in login page..

Comment: How to display failiure text instead of lblMessage.Text = "Error logging in";

Comment: You have to place a label or something to put the text in. You can also have a panel (or other) to toggle visibility on.